# jQuery Dynamic selector

Tags: jquery

How can I get the adjacent sibling of a dynamic selector?

This is what I have but it is not working.

```
var titles = $('a.highlight');
        titles.click(function(){
                $(this + " + object.hidden").show("slow");
                return false;
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var titles = $('a.highlight');
titles.click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.hidden').show("slow");
    return false;
});
```